# Convert from map to arraylist

Tags: java

I tried to convert a `Map<String,ArrayList<Object>`> to `ArrayList<Object>` using this code:

```
Collection<ArrayList<Object>> coll = map().values();
List list = new ArrayList(coll);
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
arrayList.addAll(list);
```

However, the arraylist I got still groups objects by key still as collection.

How can I convert to `ArrayList` of separate `Object`s?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And don't use raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java 8 `Stream`s:

```
List<Object> list =  map.values().stream()
                         .flatMap(ArrayList::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Without `Stream`s, you'll have to iterate over the elements of your first `List` and call `arrayList.addAll()` for each of them separately.

Comment: you forgot `.stream()` after `.values()`

Comment: `ArrayList::stream` can be replaced with `List::stream` or `Collection::stream`

Answer (score 0):

A non stream version would be:

```
List<Object> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for(ArrayList<Object> a : map.values())
      accumulator.addAll(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

same result can be achieved by using following traditional approach as well -

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Object> objects1 = new ArrayList<>();
        objects1.add("data1");
        objects1.add("data2");
        objects1.add("data3");
        map.put("key1", objects1);
        ArrayList<Object> objects2 = new ArrayList<>();
        objects2.add("data1");
        objects2.add("data2");
        objects2.add("data3");
        map.put("key2", objects2);
        Collection<ArrayList<Object>> collections = map.values();
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ArrayList<Object> collection : collections) {
            for(Object obj : collection) {
                list.add(obj);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
```

It will print the output as :

> [data1, data2, data3, data1, data2, data3]